# How do I list all sockets which are open to remote machines?

Tags: linux, security, socket

A vanilla `ss -l` lists (on my current machine) lots of open sockets, with various Netid types and many of which are only listening on localhost.

How do I get a list of all and only those sockets through which a remote machine can conceivably exchange data with the machine?

- This would include TCP, UDP, any other transport-layer protocols, RAW sockets, and any others I may not be aware of. (Is `ss` complete in this sense?)
- I believe this would exclude UNIX sockets (they're over the local filesystem only, right? or of UNIX sockets can act remotely, they should be included).
- Localhost-restricted listeners can be ignored but I don't know if there are any caveats in terms of how localhost can be represented/mapped.

The essential criteria is "any socket I can be remotely hacked through, if the listening process allowed it".

(I recall `ss` commands from a few years ago showed a *lot* fewer results than what I get now. This makes me wonder if some distributions configure `ss` to hide stuff by default. I'm looking for a `ss` or similar utility command which is as portable as possible, insofar as it won't hide anything just because it was run in a different environment. Also, from a security-theoretic point of view, we can assume for the threat model that the machine is fully under our control and is running ordinary, non-malicious software.)

So how do I list all and only the relevant sockets?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In most environments, you would only expect to find tcp, udp, raw and packet sockets.  Happily, `ss` knows about all of these.

Assuming `ss` knows all the protocols you need it to, I might use the following command.  This will exclude the "unix" sockets.  It also excludes "netlink" sockets, which are only used to communicate with the local kernel.

```
sudo ss -l -p | grep -vE '^(u_|nl )'
```

Often you do not have a lot of listening sockets.  So you can look through them all, and manually ignore any that listen on loopback IP addresses.  Alternatively, you can ask `ss` to do all the filtering:

```
sudo ss -l -p -A 'all,!unix,!netlink' 'not src 127.0.0.1 not src [::1]'
```

In both cases, the output can also include "client" udp sockets.  So it might also show DNS clients, HTTP/3 clients, ...

If you do not need to see information about the program which opened each socket, then you can remove the `-p` option, and you do not need to run `ss` (or `netstat`) with root privileges (`sudo`).

### How comprehensive is the above command?

Despite being advertised as a replacement for netstat, `ss` lacks the support for showing "udplite" sockets.

Also, the answer depends on your version of `ss` (and I guess the kernel as well).  When this answer was originally written, before [2017](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1063934), `ss` did not support "sctp".  `netstat` supported it since [February 2014](https://sourceforge.net/p/net-tools/code/ci/4932915/)).  sctp is expected specifically *inside* phone companies.  Outside of phone companies, VOIP typically uses udp.

Unfortunately if you look for a comprehensive list in `man netstat`, it gets quite confusing.  Options for sctp and udplite are shown in the first line, along with tcp, udp and raw.  Further down there's what looks like a comprehensive list of protocol *families*: `[-4|--inet] [-6|--inet6] [--unix|-x] [--inet|--ip|--tcpip] [--ax25] [--x25] [--rose] [--ash] [--bluetooth] [--ipx] [--netrom] [--ddp|--appletalk] [--econet|--ec]`.

Although `netstat` supports udplite and sctp, it does not support "dccp".  Also netstat doesn't support packet sockets (like raw sockets but including link-level headers), as selected by `ss -l -0`.  In conclusion, I hate everything, and I could probably stand to be less pedantic.

Also `ss` does not support bluetooth sockets.  Bluetooth sockets are not a traditional concern.  This could be relevant if you were doing a full audit.  Bluetooth security is quite a specific question though; I am not answering it here.

### Omitting localhost in `netstat`?

`netstat` does not have a specific way to omit sockets bound to localhost.  You could use `| grep -v` on the end.  Take care if you use the `-p` option to netstat / ss.  You might accidentally exclude some of your processes, if there is a match in the process name.  I would include the colon in your pattern, like `grep -v localhost:`.  Except the default in `ss` is to show numeric addresses, so in that case you would use `| grep -vE (127.0.0.1|\[::1\]):`.  I suppose you could try to check for processes which would be accidentally excluded, e.g. `ps ax | grep -E (127.0.0.1|\[::1\]):`.

### Is there a simpler command?

It's unfortunate about the packet sockets.  Otherwise, I might suggest a plain `netstat -l` command.  `netstat` helpfully anticipates your request and splits the output into "Internet connections", "UNIX domain sockets", and "Bluetooth connections".  You would just look at the first section.  There is no section for netlink sockets.

Suppose you're only concerned with tcp, udp, raw, and packet sockets.  For the first three types of socket you could use `netstat -l -46`.

Packet sockets are in common use.  So you would also need to train yourself to run `ss -l -0` (or `ss -l --packet`).

Unfortunately this leaves you with a big pitfall.  The problem is it is now tempting to try and combine the two commands...

### Traps to avoid with `ss`

`ss -l -046` looks appealing as a single-command answer.  However this is *not* true.  `ss -46` only shows IPv6 sockets.  `ss -64` only shows IPv4 sockets.

I suggest always sanity-checking your results.  Learn what to expect; go through each protocol and see if there's anything missing that should be there.  If you have no IPv4 addresses, or no IPv6 addresses, that's very suspicious.  You can expect most servers to have an SSH service listening on both.  Most non-servers should also show packet or raw sockets, due to using DHCP.

If you don't want to interpret the output of two different commands, one alternative might be to replace the `netstat` command with `ss -l -A inet`.  This is slightly unfortunate because when you run netstat, the exact same options would exclude ipv6 sockets.

So for a single command, you could use `ss -l -A inet,packet ...`.

IMO you might as well use `ss -l | grep ...` as I suggested in the first section.  It is easy to remember this command, and it avoids any and all confusing behaviour in the selection options of `ss`.

Although if you write scripts that use this output to automate something, then you should probably prefer to filter on a *positive* list of socket types instead.  Otherwise the script could break when `ss` starts supporting a new type of local-only socket.

Did I mention that `ss -a -A raw -f link` shows a combination of sockets from `ss -a -A raw` and `ss -a -f link` ?  Whereas `ss -a -A inet -f inet6` shows *less* sockets than `ss -a -A inet`?  I think `-f inet6` and `-f inet` are special cases, which are not documented properly.

(`-0`, `-4` and `-6` are aliases for `-f link`, `-f inet`, and `-f inet6`).

Did I mention that `ss -A packet` will show headings, but will never show any sockets?  `strace` shows that it literally does not read anything.  It seems to be because it treats packet sockets as always being "listening".  `ss` does not bother to provide a warning about this.  And this is different from raw sockets, which `ss` treats as being *simultaneously* "listening" and "non-listening".

(`man 7 raw` says that if a raw socket is *not* bound to a specific protocol which are not bound to a specific IP protocol, then it is transmit-only.  I have not checked if these are treated as listening sockets only)

Comment: Remember: "Netstat? Tuna, please!" The output of `netstat -tunapl` gives you an easyly readable output with the information you're looking for.

Comment: No.  Poster explicitly asked for raw sockets.  And any other... the `netstat` manpage is annoyingly cagey when it comes to the complete list of protocols, but I think it's saying: [-4|--inet]                   [-6|--inet6] [--unix|-x]
       [--inet|--ip|--tcpip] [--ax25] [--x25] [--rose]  [--ash]  [--bluetooth]
       [--ipx] [--netrom] [--ddp|--appletalk] [--econet|--ec]

Comment: Doh, forgot raw sockets. IIRC `netstat -w` lists them.

Comment: @Jan In `netstat -tunapl`, which of -a and -l overrides the other?

Comment: @Tim the one that comes later. Good question :-). I think it is there to make the phrase easy to remember (if Tuna is in your vocabulary :-).

Comment: Thanks. Is `netstat -tunap` better than `netstat -tunapl` for the purpose of this post, if they are not the same?

Comment: @Tim I refuse to evaluate that specific question:  Both `netstat -tunap` and `netstat -tunapl` are not adequate for the purpose of this post.  The reason is explained in comment 2 above.

Comment: Is it correct that the command that your reply here recommended to run is  `sudo ss -l -A inet,packet`? I used a different command `sudo ss -u -t -a -p`. Did I miss something by using my command?

Comment: @Tim that was indeed my suggestion. But I expected I would forget how to do that, so I suggested using the pipeline with `grep`, which can work exactly as well.  `ss -u -t -a -p` misses SCTP, for example.  I really doubt you are using SCTP, but the question asks for "and any others I may not be aware of".

Comment: May I ask why you recommended `-l` not `-a`? Are those sockets in non-LISTENING state (e.g. ESTABLISHED) not  worth?

Comment: @Tim the question is interested in `ss -l`.  It's a well-understood principle, and I didn't see any significant relevant hole in it at the time.  This is not a good place to start from the beginning, discuss why, and ask about each assumption in turn to see if it is (still) reasonable :-).

Comment: Sorry, if it is not the right place to ask. Am I wrong that  non-LISTENING sockets are also worth to look at?

Comment: I am also trying to understand `-A` of `ss`, so appreciate if you could consider  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508098/what-are-the-differences-between-f-and-a-of-ss

Comment: I’m surprised you don’t mention `lsof`; that would be my first choice.

Comment: @Wildcard if you know there is an `lsof` command that answers the question, please add it as an answer :-P.