# Difference between `nmap local-IP-address` and `nmap localhost`

Tags: services, nmap

The following IP address is for my network interface

```
$ nmap 192.168.0.142

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-09 11:33 EST
Nmap scan report for ocean (192.168.0.142)
Host is up (0.00047s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
3306/tcp open  mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.97 seconds
```

Are those services shown below but not above exactly those that are closed to the outside but open within my local machine?

Are the services whose security that I should worry about exactly those listed above?

Thanks.

```
$ nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-09 11:34 EST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00046s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned):
Not shown: 993 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
631/tcp  open  ipp
3306/tcp open  mysql
5432/tcp open  postgresql
9050/tcp open  tor-socks

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.16 seconds
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other two answers both raise very important points.  But in addition, you appear to have only scanned TCP and not UDP :-).  So there might also be UDP services you want to worry about.

UDP scanning has a number of issues that do not apply to TCP scanning.  In either case, I would start by querying the OS instead: [How do I list all sockets which are open to remote machines?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309083/how-do-i-list-all-sockets-which-are-open-to-remote-machines/)

Port scanning is still useful as a confirmation though.  Port scanning **from a different host** is a particularly good idea if you have set up a firewall, to confirm that the firewall is doing what you want.

Comment: And then the IPsec services ;) the possibilities, my God :) .... +1 (I am joking with serious things. Many people want true and tried recipes for some activities, and the reality is that were wont be a unique way of doing that for two different networks)

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean `nmap` doesn't report udp listening ports? Doe it only report tcp listening port? How do you know that?

Comment: @Tim "TCP connect scan is the default TCP scan type when SYN scan is not
           an option. This is the case when a user does not have raw packet
           privileges."

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to specify some option so that `nmap` will scan all transport listening ports (at least TCP and UCP)?

Comment: Thanks. (1) Do `ss` and `netstat` report sockets, without regard to any local firewall? (2) what is your command for port scanning for TCP and UDP? For example, `sudo nmap -p0-65535 -sU 192.168.1.97`  have been running for a while.

Comment: @Tim 1) yes 2) that is one of the issues that might apply to UDP scanning.  To be honest I have not bothered much with it.  I think you can bump up the timing when you are on your nice fast local wired network.  `-T5` seems to work ok on loopback :-), it completed a full UDP scan in less than 3 minutes.  Hint: press enter while `nmap` is running, and it will show a progress indicator.

Comment: @Tim If you're just testing the firewall, all you need to do is pass the list of ports that were shown by `nestat` / `ss` :-P.  The paranioa value of a real scan though, is it would help people start noticing  things like the intel ME stupidity.  https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/49611.html

Comment: How would you extract the  list of ports that were shown by nestat / ss an pass them to nmap to scan for tcp and udp?

Comment: @Tim Comments are not for extended discussion; let us continue this discussion at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508092/scanning-my-udp-ports/508093#508093

Answer (score 6):

If you have services that are only bound to the localhost/127.0.0.1 address, they will only show in a 127.0.0.1 `nmap` scan, and not in others scans to IP addresses on the same host.

Such is the case usually, for security reasons, of binding to 127.0.0.1, MySQL, postgresql and mongo DBs for only localhost use, redis and others.

Conversely, you can find sometimes other ports on non-localhost IPs, especially when you have vhosts in webservers bound to non-localhost IP addresses, and to only listen on those addresses.

On your specific 192.168.0.142 case, I would enquire wether that MySQL could not also be bound to 127.0.0.1.

PS A very old adage that I was taught when as a trainee, was: "More important than using the tools, is understanding how they work/the data we are given."

Concerning @roaima answer, as an example mentioned on this answer, the default port of a widely used DB, mongodb, is not on the list of ports scanned by default by `nmap`.

TLDR It is not a rule that scanning different IP addresses of the same equipment, that all the scanning data/open ports will be the same.

Alas, by network design most often than not, we do not want them to be the same. For instance in firewalls/switching equipment, we define interfaces/VLANs on a specific control network that users cannot reach for having the web management/ssh services active, and only on those interfaces. e.g. normal users cannot reach those services, they can only be reached by a VPN and/or a control room. (this is a more extreme example. I have worked in organisations where the SSH service of VMs is only present via a control network too).

Comment: And even if the same port is open on different interfaces, it may not be the same service. I.e. port 443 on a public-facing interface may run your public website, 443 on an internal-facing interface may run the Git server that you use to deploy your website.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Good point.

Answer (score 5):

Almost, but not quite.

By default `nmap` scans only 1000 ports for any given protocol (tcp, udp, whatever). So your port scans are subject to that filter. You'll see from [the documentation](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-specification.html) that you can define the set of ports to be scanned with the `-p` option, and that `-p-` means scan ports 1-65535. (Strangely, port 0 is still omitted; you have to specify it explicitly if you want to include it.)

Comment: Thanks. Does `-p0,1-65535` scan all possible ports (for any given protocol (tcp, udp, whatever))?

Comment: The documentation I linked in my answer shows `-p0-` is sufficient.

Comment: `-p0,1-65535` reveals `33060/tcp open  mysqlx`, while `-p0-` doesn't. What is the max possible port number?

Comment: The documentation I linked in my answer shows the range of ports is 0-65535 (inclusive). Please read it.

Comment: Is it correct that`-p0-65535` mean the range from 0 to 65535, both ends included.

Comment: It is. And omitting part of the range defaults 1 or 65535, so as i wrote you can shorten the term to `-p0-`. This is in the linked documentation.