# Test IPv6 windows + VirtualBox (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ipv6

I have client(Linux)-server(Windows) application.
I have Windows 7 as a main OS and Ubuntu 18.04 on a VirtualBox.
I need to test that the client can connect to the server through IPv6.
How do I setup this?

Comment: How do you have IPv6 set up? How is networking setup on virtualbox? Is the client going to be run on the host or another VM?

Comment: I am not sure that I have IPv6 set up. That is what I am asking. The network on VirtualBox is set as bridge but I can change this if needed. The client will be run on Ubuntu in VirtualBox.

Comment: Can you ping the local ipv6 address of the server from the client or vice versa? That might be enough to test

Comment: I am not sure how. I tried to use ping6 and a bunch of Link-local IPv6 addresses (fe80::...) without any success. If I understand correctly I need not a link-local address, but I don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to **test** that the client can connect to the server through IPv6.

You need to look at both ends.  Only Linux endpoints would be on-topic for this site.  (But you can see how far you can get.  And if you get far enough, you can look for what works on Windows :-).

There are only about four possibilities.

Run this command: `ip -6 addr`

1. No IPv6 address: you have no lines starting with `inet6`.  Test fail.

2. IPv6 link-local addresses only: the `inet6` lines underneath the network interface which faces your target network all begin with `fe80::`.  Technically it is possible to use link-local addresses, however some apps do not support them.  If possible, resolve this situation i.e. treat it as a test failure.

Which network interface faces your target network?

- Linux loopback interface is called `lo`.  Ignore it.
- Most Linux physical interfaces start with `e` (Ethernet), `wl` (wireless), `ww` (wide-area wireless), or less likely `ppp` (miscellaneous nonsense :-P).  In your case you will ignore these.
- Linux interfaces towards virtual machines *tend* to be named starting with `v`.  VirtualBox uses `vboxnet`, and libvirt (virt-manager) uses `virbr`.  In your case, the interface you want is almost certainly one of these.

3. Potentially routable ipv6 address:  i.e. at least one address which does not start `fe80::`.  Test has not failed - yet :-).  Continue to next step.

Having identified a routable ipv6 address, you can test connecting to it from the other system.

`ping6` is OK - *if* you know ping is not blocked by a firewall.

Prefer not to block ping in your firewalls, unless the firewall is blocking *all* incoming connections.  Otherwise, it doesn't really make sense, and you're just making life harder for yourself.

### If you cannot allow ping

Your application will have instructions *somewhere* as to which number port (and which type of port) it uses, in order to allow it through a firewall.

To test connecting to a TCP port, I would use `sudo nmap -sT -p 1,$MYPORT $MYADDRESS`.  You can also use `sudo nmap -sT -F $MYADDRESS` to scan common ports.  The latter might be useful if it shows it is possible to make some connection on a *different* port, e.g. maybe you forgot to allow the right port through a firewall.

To test UDP ports, use `-sU` instead of `-sT`.  I would not bother with `nmap -sU -F` because UDP scans can be [much slower](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508092/how-to-scan-my-computers-udp-ports) than TCP scans.

To see what a successful test looks like, scan the address `::1` (localhost).  If you do not already have an open port on localhost, open a second terminal window and run `ncat -l ::1 22`, to run a fake SSH service which `nmap` will detect.

### Link-local addresses

If you must connect to a link-local address, you will need to include a link ID.  E.g. to `ping` fe80::1 on link `vboxnet0`, run `ping6 fe80::1%vboxnet0`.  This one reason why link-local addresses are less useful: not all applications know how to specify the link ID.