# What are the differences between `-f` and `-A` of `ss`?

Tags: iproute, ss

What are the differences between `-f` and `-A` of `ss`?

Which of `-f` and `-A` is related to `-t, -u, -4, -6, -w, -x`?

Does `-A inet,packet` imply `-A tcp,udp,raw`?

I know a few socket concepts, but can't figure out the terminology in the manpage.

Thanks.

> -f
>
> Display sockets of type FAMILY. Currently the following families are
>   supported: unix, inet, inet6, link, netlink.
>
> -A Query
>
> List of socket tables to dump, separated by commas. The following
>   identifiers are understood: all, inet, tcp, udp, raw, unix, packet,
>   netlink, unix_dgram, unix_stream, unix_seqpacket, packet_raw,
>   packet_dgram.

Comment: Answerd by quote and clearly by the man page you've read

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 can you explain what the manpage says?

Answer (score 1):

`-4, -6, -x` - as per man page.

`-t`, `-u`, `-w` - all correspond to socket tables.

> Does `-A inet,packet` imply `-A tcp,udp,raw?`

The table `inet` implies all of `tcp`, `udp`, `raw`, and presumably also `dccp` and `sctp`.  I assume `all` is synthetic at some level, so I assume `inet` is similar.

I notice when overlapping "socket table" values are specified, e.g. `-A tcp,inet` , `ss` does not show duplicates.

I think `-A packet` and `-A raw` are disjoint.  So I think `-A inet,packet` should show strictly more than `-A tcp,udp,raw`...

BEWARE

`-A raw` and `-A packet` look like they do related things, however there are some practical differences.  `ss` currently treats all packet sockets as listening sockets,[*] but (most?) raw sockets are shown both if the `-l` option is passed AND if the `-l` option is not passed.  Usually there are not many raw and packet sockets in use.  If you look at this and decide you don't even want to trust `-l` here, you could just list all of the raw and packet sockets using `ss -a -A raw,packet` instead.

Even more bizarrely, `ss` cannot decide whether the packets in the `raw` table count as belonging to the `link` address family, or not:

```
# ss -A raw -p
State    Recv-Q   Send-Q     Local Address:Port             Peer Address:Port                                                                                   
UNCONN   0        0                0.0.0.0:ipproto-255           0.0.0.0:*       users:(("atop",pid=26422,fd=4))                                                
UNCONN   0        0                      *:ipv6-icmp                   *:*       users:(("NetworkManager",pid=1317,fd=17))                                      
# ss -f link -p
Netid    Recv-Q    Send-Q       Local Address:Port         Peer Address:Port                                                                                    
p_raw    0         0                        *:wlp2s0                   *         users:(("dhclient",pid=20548,fd=5))                                            
p_dgr    0         0                  [34958]:wlp2s0                   *         users:(("wpa_supplicant",pid=1406,fd=13))                                      
p_dgr    0         0                      [0]:*                        *         users:(("wpa_supplicant",pid=1406,fd=16))                                      
p_dgr    0         0                      [0]:*                        *         users:(("wpa_supplicant",pid=1406,fd=12))                            
# ss -A raw -f link -p
Netid  State   Recv-Q  Send-Q   Local Address:Port           Peer Address:Port                                                                                  
???    UNCONN  0       0              0.0.0.0:ipproto-255         0.0.0.0:*      users:(("atop",pid=26422,fd=4))                                                
icmp6  UNCONN  0       0                    *:ipv6-icmp                 *:*      users:(("NetworkManager",pid=1317,fd=17))
```

Similarly it seems unable to decide whether the two options are combined with AND or OR.  `ss -A all -f link` gives the same output as `ss -A all`.  But `ss -A raw -f link` is giving fewer lines than `ss -f link`.

Also, the concept of a `link` address family seems unique to `ss`.  Linux does not have `AF_LINK`, it has `AF_PACKET`.

The name "socket tables" sounds like it would refer to native tables inside the kernel.  So it would be very efficient to list exactly `tcp` sockets for example, we just list the entire table.

However I can see old plain-text /proc interfaces listed in the old [`man netstat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/netstat.8.html)... and those do not match exactly, e.g. there are separate tables for `tcp` and `tcp6`.  Hmm.

The reality is that the kernel hash table is for inet, then there is another table for inet6, ... I can't really make sense of `ss` "socket tables" v.s. [`sock_diag`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sock_diag.7.html), it seems made up by `ss`.

Options like the FILTER expressions mention in `man ss` *might* print much less compared to the size of the table they need to scan.  In this sense they might be less efficient than dumping a whole list returned by the kernel.

I think it is unlikely we need to worry about the efficiency though.

### Notes

[*] Proof: `strace` shows that `ss` does *nothing*, when you ask it to list packet sockets without passing `-l`:

```
$ strace -f -e '!mprotect,mmap,read,write,lseek' ss -A packet

...

openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=258624, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 136384, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbffcade000
mmap(0x7fbffcae4000, 65536, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7fbffcae4000
mmap(0x7fbffcaf4000, 24576, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7fbffcaf4000
mmap(0x7fbffcafa000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b000) = 0x7fbffcafa000
mmap(0x7fbffcafc000, 13504, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbffcafc000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbffcadc000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fbffcadce40) = 0
munmap(0x7fbffcdc7000, 199180)          = 0
set_tid_address(0x7fbffcadd110)         = 2588
set_robust_list(0x7fbffcadd120, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7fbffcae4c50, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fbffcaf1030}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7fbffcae4ce0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fbffcaf1030}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", {f_type=SELINUX_MAGIC, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=0, f_bfree=0, f_bavail=0, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={val=[0, 0]}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096, f_flags=ST_VALID|ST_RELATIME}) = 0
statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", {f_type=SELINUX_MAGIC, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=0, f_bfree=0, f_bavail=0, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={val=[0, 0]}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096, f_flags=ST_VALID|ST_RELATIME}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x563e25ce6000
brk(0x563e25d07000)                     = 0x563e25d07000
access("/etc/selinux/config", F_OK)     = 0
mmap(NULL, 1052672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbffc9db000
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=35, ws_col=150, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0), ...}) = 0

[ss output starts here]
State              Recv-Q              Send-Q                           Local Address:Port                             Peer Address:Port              
[ss output ends]

munmap(0x7fbffc9db000, 1052672)         = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between `-f` and `-A`?

Comment: @Tim last two paragraphs.

Comment: (1) I am not sure what your last paragraph mean. Is it about `-f`? What is "filter" and "the other types of filters"? `-f` specifies family, not filter. (2) Why are `-4, -6, -x` related to `-f`, while `-t, -u, -w` to `-A`?

Comment: @Tim there is not a separate table for `listening` sockets for example.  So `ss state listening` might only print a few sockets, but will still have to scan through all sockets on the machine.  It is an implementation / performance detail.

Comment: -f is said to specify socket type family. Is -f unrelated to filter, correct? What is the difference between -f and -A? Why are -4, -6, -x related to -f, while -t, -u, -w to -A? –

Comment: @Tim strangely it looks like "socket tables" might be a detail specific to `ss`, and "address family" is really the set you can query from the kernel as a table.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sock_diag.7.html